# XPath Java count of child nodes

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to count some child nodes of a given xml. But it always returns me 0 and I can't figure out why.

Here's the xml:

```
<FirstOne xmlns:xxx="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Formulas xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <xxx:yyy>
      <aa:bb>something</aa:bb>
      <cc:dd>something</cc:dd>
    </xxx:yyy>
    <xxx:yyy>
      <aa:bb>something</aa:bb>
      <cc:dd>something</cc:dd>
    </xxx:yyy>
    <xxx:yyy>
      <aa:bb>something</aa:bb>
      <cc:dd>something</cc:dd>
    </xxx:yyy>
  </Formulas>

</FirstOne>
```

I want to count the number of "xxx:yyy". In this example 3.
I tried the following:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File(fileArray[i].toString())));
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    String expression;
    expression = "count(//Formulas/xxx:yyy)";
    Double result = (Double) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
```

It always gives me 0.0 ...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try just `count(//Formulas/yyy)`

Comment: @betlista I'd post that as answer before someone pulls a SCITE on you

Comment: Can you tell me, what the SCITE stands for?

Comment: @betlista http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite-on-mso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `xxx` is the tag prefix, use just `count(//Formulas/yyy)`.

Comment: That XPath would select `yyy` elements that are not in a namespace, and the fact that it appears to work when the `yyy` elements are namespaced is an implementation-specific side effect of parsing with a non-namespace-aware DOM parser.

Comment: @IanRoberts Good point.  Betlista should update the answer mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

The problems all stem from the namespaces.

Firstly, XPath evaluation is only defined over namespace-well-formed XML, so you need to ensure that the `aa` and `cc` prefixes are properly mapped to namespace URIs in the XML.

Secondly, you need to parse the XML into a DOM tree using a *namespace-aware* parser (for what I can only assume are historical reasons, `DocumentBuilderFactory` is not namespace-aware by default).

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setValidating(false);
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File(fileArray[i].toString())));
```

Now you have a proper namespace-well-formed DOM tree you need to handle the namespaces correctly in the XPath.  You need to define a `NamespaceContext` telling the `XPath` how to relate prefixes and namespace URIs.  Annoyingly there's no default implementation of this interface available in the core Java libraries but there are third-party implementations such as [Spring's `SimpleNamespaceContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/util/xml/SimpleNamespaceContext.html), or it's only three methods to implement it yourself.  With a `SimpleNamespaceContext`:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
SimpleNamespaceContext nsCtx = new SimpleNamespaceContext();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(nsCtx);

nsCtx.bindNamespaceUri("x", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

With this context in place you can now select namespaced nodes in your XPath expression:

```
String expression = "count(//Formulas/x:yyy)";
```

(the prefixes you use are the ones in the `NamespaceContext`, not necessarily the ones in the original XML source).

---

While *some* DOM parsers and XPath implementations might let you get away with parsing non-namespace-aware and omitting the prefixes in the XPath expressions, this is an implementation detail and the behaviour is not defined by the specifications.  It might work in one version but fail in another, or behave differently if you add additional JARs to your project that change the default parser, etc.